# Inserting into table using Python and MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql

I am using Python and MySQLdb, I have a table which is displayed below but I get error message each time I try to insert into the table.

> INSERT INTO reviews (entry,created_time, user_id, branch_id, title)VALUES('branches that would lead use to the ciyrt', '2011-09-20 00:24:24',1, ,1, 'oogletivers')

```
   CREATE TABLE reviews
   (
     id int(9)  unsigned not null  primary key auto_increment,
 entry text  not null , 
 created_time timestamp not null,
 user_id tinyint unsigned  not null references users(id),
 branch_id tinyint unsigned not null references branches( id),
 title varchar(255),
 FULLTEXT(title, entry)
      )
```

> mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1, 'oogletivers')' at line 1")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two commas without anything between them. Remove one.

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe that I could miss that.